# Mutation Response from Schema When Object is Returned

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, graphql, apollo

I am running a graphql mutation `const [updateUser] = useMutation(UPDATE_USER);` and I want to add the mutation response `(interface myResoponse)`.

However, I am unable to understand how I can formulate the response type in this case. This is the mutation:

```
updateUser(email: String!, input: UpdateUserInput!): User!
```

In the schema, the response type is a whole object like this:

```
type User {
  email: String!
  firstName: String
  id: Int!
  lastName: String
  phoneNumber: String!
}
```

If I check via GraphQL code generator, this is what I get:

```
export type User = {
   __typename?: 'User',
  email: Scalars['String'],
  firstName?: Maybe<Scalars['String']>,
  id: Scalars['Int'],
  lastName?: Maybe<Scalars['String']>,
  phoneNumber: Scalars['String'],
};
```

But I am unable to use 'Scalars' in my Typescript code. How can I write the response interface for this mutation? What pattern should I use in my response types? From the schema or the code generator?

Answer (score 0):

This may help transform your gql to typescript when you compile it you can find more information and instructions here: https://medium.com/the-guild/graphql-code-generator-a34e3785e6fb

Now, we have a generic JSON structure, and if we want to turn our schema into TypeScript type definition, we need to compile it with the following template:

```
{{#each models}}
  export type {{name}} = {
  {{#each fields}}
    {{name ~}} {{#unless required ~}} ? {{~ /unless ~}} : {{ type }};
    {{/each}}
    }
{{/each}}
```

Now when we use the two together, we will get:

```
export type Person {
  name: string;
  age?: number;
}
```